# Background image appears zoomed in on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, background-image

I have a series of webpages that utilise background images in the divs. These work perfectly on desktop and mobile but appear very zoomed in on an iPad. Can anybody give me any pointers that I need to look at here. I’m thinking possibly something like a media query may help or should I avoid background images for the sake of Ipad completely?

Comment: Can you show us exactly what CSS you are using? For example, IOS does not deal with background-attachment: fixed - well it makes the background look zoomed in. There may be other things you are using which are not supported the same way too.

Comment: HI.....@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 481px) 
  and (max-device-width: 768px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1){
         background-attachment: scroll;
 background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
   background-size: cover;
    }

Answer (score 0):

you can use media queries to make it responsive for tabs.
Just adjust the size of images for the particular range of pixels.

```
    ex : @media screen only (min-width:481px) and (max-width:768px){
         /*your css to adjust the image size*/
    }
```

You can try this link
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Thanks but what is the css code required in the section?